# Two submit buttons

Tags: html

I have two forms on a same page and I have two submit buttons...so how do I check if the user filled out the first form before clicking the submit button on second form? The first form posts the data to php page which presents on a same page as the html and the second form sends the data to another PHP page with thank you message....I mean how do force the user to finish the first form before clicking the submit button on the second form? if the user hits the submit button on the second form, the form directs to thank you page with out checking if the user finished the first form..how do I stop that?

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="submited" value="true" />
<label for="file">Choose Photo:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="file_selected = true;" required>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<form action="Send.php" method="post">
First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" required><br>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" required><br>
Choose Username:<input type="text" name="username" required><br>
Age:<input type="text" name="age" required><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: You should try to use Javascript/jQuery on this.

Comment: And why do you have the two forms on the page if one is required before the other? From a usability standpoints this isn't desirable. Seems like they should be presented in the order they should be completed (display form 1, submit, display form 2, submit) at the very least, look in to using a wizard format (step 1, step 2, etc.)

Comment: you could use some javascript... `<form ... onsubmit="validate();">`  Make sure validate has the logic - `for each field, if not filled out, return false;`

Comment: @BradChristie the first form is to let the user upload picture and the second one is to collect another information..@John could you show me how?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name field  and then access the value on the server side.
For example:

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitOne" />`

If you're using php you could use something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitOne'])){ /* first one pressed */ }
```

There are also some other options like using jQuery or javascript to validate first.

Try: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/